# How does Symfony load the test environment for end-to-end tests?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm working on another PHP project that uses end-to-end tests and `.env` files. However before running the tests I need to modify the `.env` file to point to the test database (instead of the development one). When I work on Symfony projects I don't believe I need to do that, it just loads the test environment automatically.

I know from some previous experience with older versions that there used to be a different front controller for each environment, like `app.php`, `app_dev.php` etc. but afaik that isn't the case now.

How does Symfony know to load the test environment for end-to-end tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flex recipe for the `phpunit-bridge` includes a [`phpunit.xml` file](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/phpunit-bridge/5.1/phpunit.xml.dist) that sets the `APP_ENV` variable to `test`. That triggers symfony to load the appropiate `.env.test` file.

During tests the front controller isn't normally used, as the bridge instantiates a `Request` object and passes it to the application kernel directly. But in end-to-end tests using `PantherTestCase`, the framework boots the project in the built-in PHP webserver, which is still controlled by environment variables.

This is better explained in [the book](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/17-tests.html#writing-functional-tests-for-controllers) than the testing chapter of the documentation itself:

> The $client variable simulates a browser. Instead of making HTTP calls
> to the server though, it calls the Symfony application directly. This
> strategy has several benefits: it is much faster than having
> round-trips between the client and the server, but it also allows the
> tests to introspect the state of the services after each HTTP request.

And in the [Panther announcement](https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-symfony-panther-a-browser-testing-and-web-scrapping-library-for-php#using-panther-to-run-the-scenario-in-a-browser):

> However, WebTestCase doesn’t use a real web browser. It simulates one
> with pure PHP components. It doesn’t even use the HTTP protocol: it
> creates instances of HttpFoundation’s Request objects, pass them to
> the Symfony kernel, and allows to assert on the HttpFoundation
> Response instance returned by the app.
> [...]
> Under the hood Panther has:
>
> - **started your project with the built-in PHP webserver on localhost:9000**
> - started the version of Chromedriver shipped with the library to automate your local Chrome
> - executed the browsing scenario defined in the test with Chrome in headless mode

Comment: So are you saying that when I run any `WebTestCase` it starts a new PHP process with a server to listen for requests? Do you have any information about where this happens?

Comment: @mickadoo No, `WebTestCase` doesn't use the internal webserver, it instatiates the `Request` object and passes it to the application kernel directly, there are no actual HTTP requests. But `PantherTestCase` does use the webserver, and `APP_ENV` still applies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a bit clearer now. I didn't understand how it was working for `PantherTestCase` as I imagined it would be something like firing requests to the local server but seems that Symfony spins up its own server so would be able to set env variables for that

Comment: @mickadoo I've included some links and quotes that address those.

Answer (score 1):

Which environment to use is generally set in `phpunit.xml.dist`.

This is more a PhpUnit thing than a Symfony one.

You should have an entry like:

```xml
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
<!-- ... -->
</php>
```

By using `force=true`, it will override the value of any existing `APP_ENV` environment variable.

`WebTestCase` will "simulate" the requests, as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#application-tests). If you use something like Panther, the tests will fire up an internal web server and make "real" HTTP requests, as explained [here](https://github.com/symfony/panther#testing-usage).

In either case, the `APP_ENV` used by the application is the one defined on PhpUnit configuration.

Comment: I've seen that you can set env variables in tests pretty easily. But for end to end tests it's a separate process (if I understand it correctly) and so would just be handled like any other request. Maybe my impression of WebTestCase is wrong, I imagined it would send something like a curl request but maybe that doesn't happen at all

Comment: The environment variables set by PhpUnit will affect the _receiving_ side of the request, logically. It doesn't matter it makes a _real_ request or an internal request (this kind of test [can make both](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#application-tests)). But addressing your question: how does "Symfony" know which environment to boot? By using the APP_ENV environment variable set by PhpUnit.

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit slow to catch on here but if I imagine an e2e test as like sending a curl request then it can't just decide to set environment variables on the server. The server would just serve the request as normal (from what I understand). I get that PHPUnit can load environment variables _for the PHPUnit_ process but I imagined the process to handle the request is different to that.

Comment: If you are using Symfony testing (as you mention in your question), the requests are simulated and not "real" e2e tests. Which is fine, since from the point of view of the client the response is indistinguishible from real responses. If you need "real" e2e tests, testing all the infrastructure layers in between, then you'll need to set those up with the corresponding environment variables in place (set up a real webserver, set up a real PHP server, set-up a real DB, and set-up tests to run over something like Panther to make real requests and parse the responses).

Comment: But even using `PantherTestCase` (that makes "real" HTTP requests), it will end up firing the internal webserver, and using the APP_ENV setup in PhpUnit configuration.

Comment: Ok, I guess the answer then is that it's not the same thing using `WebTestCase` as firing off HTTP requests to your local dev server (but somehow knowing to load a test env). From what you're saying the `WebTestCase` will either handle the request internally or create a new server using the test env variables. Does that sound right?

**Edit**: I had a look at Panther and it checks out, the readme mentions
"In test mode, Panther automatically starts your application using the PHP built-in web-server."

Comment: `WebTestCase` does not fire an internal web server. It simulates requests. To fire actual HTTP requests, you'll need something else, like Panther. I've added this to the answer and mentioned in my previous comment.